# Hide or remove div with dynamic class name

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I had a problem that a **new dynamic div is added with the dynamic class name** while the page is refreshed every time.

For example

```
<div class="ABGeGGCcJeBCDEGD" data-app-name="">
```

Here the class=" ABGeGGCcJeBCDEGD", when I reload the page the class name is changed automatically.

So, I need to remove or hide that div.

**Note**
   The div is not present in the code side, but it is created dynamically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In hope of being able to help and also out of curiosity, can you tell us how are you creating this dynamic div?

Comment: Find a way to differentiate this div from other elements. For example enumerate all elements found by document.querySelectorAll('div[data-app-name]') and check which ones have a class name of a certain length or that matches a regexp pattern.

Comment: is it just one div whose class is constantly changing, or are there many more divs, depending on how many times u reload the page, with different class names?

Comment: Sorry @Jorge.V, I don't know how it's created. And also I found the solution (a JQuery function) for removing the dynamically created divs. Here it is **parent().prev().remove()**

Answer (score 0):

You should find another way to identify div instead of class name, e.g. DOM tree.

Also you can try to make "white list" of visible divs. Something like

- Make ALL divs hidden
- Get white list and show divs with these classes.

Comment: Hi @Dim_K, as you said that **Make ALL divs hidden**, It is created dynamically. So, we don't know which div is created and also which class is contained.

Comment: @ManikandanC do you mean you don't know WHEN is it created and can't call js code after creating? Because i don't see problems hide divs including dynamically created. Just do something like this `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` and change CSS `display` property with loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use event on id 
Example is here. 
$('#testDiv'). remove()
Let me know if this case is not going to work

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But it only contains the class name and doesn't contain ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options, as far as I can see.

**1. Does the class always start or end the same way?**

If so, you can target that in CSS.

```
div[class^="ABGe"] { display: none; }
div[class$="DEGD"] { display: none; }
```

**2. Does the element have any other classes or attributes that you can target.**

If so, you can target them in CSS instead.

```
div[data-app-name] { display: none; }
```

**3. Can you modify the markup?**

If so, you can wrap the element in something that won't change.

```
<div class="hide-contents">
    <div class="ABGeGGCcJeBCDEGD" data-app-name="">
</div>
```

You can then target that in CSS.

```
.hide-contents > div { display: none; }
```

I hope one of those options is useful.

Comment: Thanks, @James, I'll try these and will inform you which one suit for me.

Comment: Hi @James, I had used the **parent().prev().remove()** JQuery function and removed the dynamically created div.